# WPF databinding ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, progress-bar

I'm making a WPF application where I use `WebClient` to download file. I want to show the `ProgressPercentage` within a `ProgressBar` controller. I have a method in a class where I use `WebClient` to download file. My question is how do I Databind the `ProgressBar` to the `e.ProgressPercentage`.

Method in a Class (DownloadFile):

```
public async Task DownloadProtocol(string address, string location)
{

        Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            //client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage);
                //ProgressBar = e.ProgressPercentage???
            };

            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Cancelled == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
                }

            };

            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, location);
        }

}
```

ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="130,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249"/>
```

Comment: `ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage` ?

Comment: I can't access my ProgressBar in another class? @PhilippeParé

Comment: You can create an even (i.e. "public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged"), and raise it each time the DownloadProgressChanged fires. You then make your progressbar controller subscribe to that event.

Comment: Thank for your respons @Dietz, but can't you come with an example? I'm quite new to WPF. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a clean solution you need a `ViewModel` class and in it we create a `StartDownload` method and you can call it by a `Command` or under a `button` click in your `window`.

On the other hand there is a good `Type` named `IProgress<T>`. It works as a *informer* for us and you can play with it like the following sample ;)

---

**Inside DownloadViewModel.cs:**

```
public sealed class DownloadViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IProgress<double> _progress;
    private double _progressValue;

    public double ProgressValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _progressValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _progressValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DownloadViewModel()
    {
        _progress = new Progress<double>(ProgressValueChanged);
    }

    private void ProgressValueChanged(double d)
    {
        ProgressValue = d;
    }

    public async void StartDownload(string address, string location)
    {
        await new MyDlClass().DownloadProtocol(_progress, address, location);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

**Inside MyDlClass. cs**

```
public class MyDlClass
{
    public async Task DownloadProtocol(IProgress<double> progress, string address, string location)
    {

        Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            //client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage);
                progress.Report(e.ProgressPercentage);
            };

            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Cancelled == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
                }

            };

            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, location);
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Inside `MyWindow.Xaml.cs` & `MyWindow.Xaml`:**

Now you should fill your window `DataContext` with an instance of `DownloadViewModel` class (by Xaml or Code-Behind).

Binding to `ProgressValue` property of `DownloadViewModel.cs` class:

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="130,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249"
             Minimum="0"
             Maximum="100"
             Value="{Binding Path=ProgressValue}"/>
```

Finnaly, write in your button OnClick:

```
if(this.DataContext!=null)
   ((DownloadViewModel)this.DataContext).StartDownload("__@Address__","__@Location__");
else
    MessageBox.Show("DataContext is Null!");
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RAM. I sat my Datacontext = DownloadViewModel class, but the progressbar doesn't change?

Comment: Sorry i had a bit mistake here:  `_progressValue = d;` It must be: `ProgressValue = d;` . Also for a better implementation I changed the `public Progress property` to a simple `private member` in the `ViewModel` class. Now  I changed the answer and tested it myself. It works...

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `IProgress<double> progress` parameter to your method, whenever your client wants to update progress then call `progress.Report()`. `IProgress` on your view/window side will point to a method where you'll implement the `MyProgressBar.Value = value` or whatever else.

Using `IProgress` effectively removes the interaction with the target control that will provide updates, in addition it also takes care of calling the dispatcher so you don't get usual invalid cross-thread call errors.

See this post for an example:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx